# C++ running file with included library failes without compiling error (CMake / CLion)

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I got the following problem; I have my super library called mylib: it looks like this:

My project folder is called library...

---

*mylib.hpp*

```
namespace XYZ {

#ifndef LIBRARY_MYLIB_HPP
#define LIBRARY_MYLIB_HPP

    int add(int, int);

#endif //LIBRARY_MYLIB_HPP

}
```

*mylib.cpp*

```
#include "mylib.hpp"

namespace XYZ {

    int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

---

They are in the same directory.

I Build it using CMake with the following CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(library)

add_library(library SHARED mylib.cpp)
```

Building Output:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/library.dir/mylib.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX shared library liblibrary.dll
[100%] Built target library
```

This works, this gives me a *.dll file like it's supposed to.

---

**I now try to use this library in my other project**

I copied the .hpp file into the project location.
my main.cpp looks like this:

---

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mylib.hpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello";
    std::cout << XYZ::add(5, 7) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(uselib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(uselib ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(uselib C:/User/........./liblibrary.dll)
```

*Building output:*

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/uselib.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable uselib.exe
[100%] Built target uselib
```

---

Works. Well now to my problem.

Once I try to start it, it crashes with the following exit code:

```
C:\Users\......\uselib.exe

Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

When I comment the method call out, it works like a charm.

I've been stuck here for hours, any help?

Comment: Seems like you're doing most of it pretty good. Maybe a basic check: is the dll available in whatever the working dir you're executing your app from? (or via PATH)

Comment: @hauron I managed to get it to run after i copied the .dll into the execution directory. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)` is STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND. This would indicate that the dll isn't available to the program at runtime. In windows, the search path for a dll is as follows:

1. The directory where the executable for the current process is
   located.
2. The current directory.
3. The Windows system directory. The `GetSystemDirectory` function
   retrieves the path of this directory.
4. The Windows directory. The `GetWindowsDirectory` function retrieves
   the path of this directory.
5. The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

Verify that liblibrary.dll is located in a place it can be found by the executable.

Once you have done that, you may want to add a macro to help you copy the dll to the executable directory as part of your build. This can be done in cmake like so:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET uselib POST_BUILD        # Adds a post-build event to uselib
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different  # which executes "cmake - E copy_if_different..."
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/liblibrary.dll"      # this is in-file
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:uselib>)                 # this is out-file path
```

Comment: I managed to get it to run after i copied the .dll into the execution directory. thanks a lot!